# Best way to convert a Unicode URL to ASCII (UTF-8 percent-escaped) in Python?

Tags: python, url, unicode, utf-8

I'm wondering what's the best way -- or if there's a simple way with the standard library -- to convert a URL with Unicode chars in the domain name and path to the equivalent ASCII URL, encoded with domain as IDNA and the path %-encoded, as per RFC 3986.

I get from the user a URL in UTF-8. So if they've typed in `http://➡.ws/♥` I get `'http://\xe2\x9e\xa1.ws/\xe2\x99\xa5'` in Python. And what I want out is the ASCII version: `'http://xn--hgi.ws/%E2%99%A5'`.

What I do at the moment is split the URL up into parts via a regex, and then manually IDNA-encode the domain, and separately encode the path and query string with different `urllib.quote()` calls.

```
# url is UTF-8 here, eg: url = u'http://➡.ws/㉌'.encode('utf-8')
match = re.match(r'([a-z]{3,5})://(.+\.[a-z0-9]{1,6})'
                 r'(:\d{1,5})?(/.*?)(\?.*)?$', url, flags=re.I)
if not match:
    raise BadURLException(url)
protocol, domain, port, path, query = match.groups()

try:
    domain = unicode(domain, 'utf-8')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    return ''  # bad UTF-8 chars in domain
domain = domain.encode('idna')

if port is None:
    port = ''

path = urllib.quote(path)

if query is None:
    query = ''
else:
    query = urllib.quote(query, safe='=&?/')

url = protocol + '://' + domain + port + path + query
# url is ASCII here, eg: url = 'http://xn--hgi.ws/%E3%89%8C'
```

Is this correct? Any better suggestions? Is there a simple standard-library function to do this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### Code:

```
import urlparse, urllib

def fixurl(url):
    # turn string into unicode
    if not isinstance(url,unicode):
        url = url.decode('utf8')

    # parse it
    parsed = urlparse.urlsplit(url)

    # divide the netloc further
    userpass,at,hostport = parsed.netloc.rpartition('@')
    user,colon1,pass_ = userpass.partition(':')
    host,colon2,port = hostport.partition(':')

    # encode each component
    scheme = parsed.scheme.encode('utf8')
    user = urllib.quote(user.encode('utf8'))
    colon1 = colon1.encode('utf8')
    pass_ = urllib.quote(pass_.encode('utf8'))
    at = at.encode('utf8')
    host = host.encode('idna')
    colon2 = colon2.encode('utf8')
    port = port.encode('utf8')
    path = '/'.join(  # could be encoded slashes!
        urllib.quote(urllib.unquote(pce).encode('utf8'),'')
        for pce in parsed.path.split('/')
    )
    query = urllib.quote(urllib.unquote(parsed.query).encode('utf8'),'=&?/')
    fragment = urllib.quote(urllib.unquote(parsed.fragment).encode('utf8'))

    # put it back together
    netloc = ''.join((user,colon1,pass_,at,host,colon2,port))
    return urlparse.urlunsplit((scheme,netloc,path,query,fragment))

print fixurl('http://\xe2\x9e\xa1.ws/\xe2\x99\xa5')
print fixurl('http://\xe2\x9e\xa1.ws/\xe2\x99\xa5/%2F')
print fixurl(u'http://Åsa:abc123@➡.ws:81/admin')
print fixurl(u'http://➡.ws/admin')
```

### Output:

> `http://xn--hgi.ws/%E2%99%A5`
>   `http://xn--hgi.ws/%E2%99%A5/%2F`
>   `http://%C3%85sa:abc123@xn--hgi.ws:81/admin`
>   `http://xn--hgi.ws/admin`

### Read more:

- [urllib.quote()](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote)
- [urlparse.urlparse()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse)
- [urlparse.urlunparse()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlunparse)
- [urlparse.urlsplit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit)
- [urlparse.urlunsplit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlunsplit)

### Edits:

- Fixed the case of already quoted characters in the string.
- Changed `urlparse`/`urlunparse` to `urlsplit`/`urlunsplit`.
- Don't encode user and port information with the hostname. (Thanks Jehiah)
- When "@" is missing, don't treat the host/port as user/pass! (Thanks hupf)

Comment: Nice solution, thanks. Good call about using urlparse/unparse, and noticing the case of already-quoted chars in the input.

But I'm unsure why you need the split('/') logic, because urllib.quote() already considers slashes safe.

See also my new, doctested, and somewhat more complete solution below.

Comment: The problem is that '/' is considered a path separator, while '%2F' is not. If I just unquote the string, they become one and the same. Maybe it would be better to never unquote the path at all, and encode all existing '%' as '%25'..?

Comment: netloc != domain, so you should parse the domain out from `user:pass@domain:port` first then convert to idna

Comment: The edited version with user/port information support does no more work for URLs without user or port information. The username, password and port should be parsed out conditionally. I used the following regex to do this: `(?:(?P<user>[^:@]+)(?::(?P<password>[^:@]+))?@)?(?P<host>[^:]+)(?::(?P<port>[0-9]+))?`, then accessed the values using the groupdict: `p.match(parsed.netloc).groupdict()`

Comment: It's worth noting that urllib/2/requests don't support credentials embedded in the "netloc" as it isn't standard for http urls.  So they'll have to be removed and passed in as seperate params on use.

Answer (score 5):

the code given by MizardX isnt 100% correct. This example wont work:

example.com/folder/?page=2

check out django.utils.encoding.iri_to_uri() to convert unicode URL to ASCII urls.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/

Comment: Issue and answer are almost 10 years old, and this still works, and is still the best answer that I see. If you look at Django 2.0 code, it imports `from urllib.parse import quote` and returns `quote(iri, safe="/#%[]=:;$&()+,!?*@'~")`, so that might be the direction that any modern onlooker might want to go in.

Answer (score 2):

there's some RFC-3896 *url parsing* work underway (e.g. as part of the Summer Of Code) but nothing in the standard library yet AFAIK -- and nothing much on the *uri encoding* side of things either, again AFAIK.  So you might as well go with MizardX's elegant approach.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, with these comments and some bug-fixing in my own code (it didn't handle fragments at all), I've come up with the following `canonurl()` function -- returns a canonical, ASCII form of the URL:

```
import re
import urllib
import urlparse

def canonurl(url):
    r"""Return the canonical, ASCII-encoded form of a UTF-8 encoded URL, or ''
    if the URL looks invalid.

    >>> canonurl('    ')
    ''
    >>> canonurl('www.google.com')
    'http://www.google.com/'
    >>> canonurl('bad-utf8.com/path\xff/file')
    ''
    >>> canonurl('svn://blah.com/path/file')
    'svn://blah.com/path/file'
    >>> canonurl('1234://badscheme.com')
    ''
    >>> canonurl('bad$scheme://google.com')
    ''
    >>> canonurl('site.badtopleveldomain')
    ''
    >>> canonurl('site.com:badport')
    ''
    >>> canonurl('http://123.24.8.240/blah')
    'http://123.24.8.240/blah'
    >>> canonurl('http://123.24.8.240:1234/blah?q#f')
    'http://123.24.8.240:1234/blah?q#f'
    >>> canonurl('\xe2\x9e\xa1.ws')  # tinyarro.ws
    'http://xn--hgi.ws/'
    >>> canonurl('  http://www.google.com:80/path/file;params?query#fragment  ')
    'http://www.google.com:80/path/file;params?query#fragment'
    >>> canonurl('http://\xe2\x9e\xa1.ws/\xe2\x99\xa5')
    'http://xn--hgi.ws/%E2%99%A5'
    >>> canonurl('http://\xe2\x9e\xa1.ws/\xe2\x99\xa5/pa%2Fth')
    'http://xn--hgi.ws/%E2%99%A5/pa/th'
    >>> canonurl('http://\xe2\x9e\xa1.ws/\xe2\x99\xa5/pa%2Fth;par%2Fams?que%2Fry=a&b=c')
    'http://xn--hgi.ws/%E2%99%A5/pa/th;par/ams?que/ry=a&b=c'
    >>> canonurl('http://\xe2\x9e\xa1.ws/\xe2\x99\xa5?\xe2\x99\xa5#\xe2\x99\xa5')
    'http://xn--hgi.ws/%E2%99%A5?%E2%99%A5#%E2%99%A5'
    >>> canonurl('http://\xe2\x9e\xa1.ws/%e2%99%a5?%E2%99%A5#%E2%99%A5')
    'http://xn--hgi.ws/%E2%99%A5?%E2%99%A5#%E2%99%A5'
    >>> canonurl('http://badutf8pcokay.com/%FF?%FE#%FF')
    'http://badutf8pcokay.com/%FF?%FE#%FF'
    >>> len(canonurl('google.com/' + 'a' * 16384))
    4096
    """
    # strip spaces at the ends and ensure it's prefixed with 'scheme://'
    url = url.strip()
    if not url:
        return ''
    if not urlparse.urlsplit(url).scheme:
        url = 'http://' + url

    # turn it into Unicode
    try:
        url = unicode(url, 'utf-8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return ''  # bad UTF-8 chars in URL

    # parse the URL into its components
    parsed = urlparse.urlsplit(url)
    scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment = parsed

    # ensure scheme is a letter followed by letters, digits, and '+-.' chars
    if not re.match(r'[a-z][-+.a-z0-9]*$', scheme, flags=re.I):
        return ''
    scheme = str(scheme)

    # ensure domain and port are valid, eg: sub.domain.<1-to-6-TLD-chars>[:port]
    match = re.match(r'(.+\.[a-z0-9]{1,6})(:\d{1,5})?$', netloc, flags=re.I)
    if not match:
        return ''
    domain, port = match.groups()
    netloc = domain + (port if port else '')
    netloc = netloc.encode('idna')

    # ensure path is valid and convert Unicode chars to %-encoded
    if not path:
        path = '/'  # eg: 'http://google.com' -> 'http://google.com/'
    path = urllib.quote(urllib.unquote(path.encode('utf-8')), safe='/;')

    # ensure query is valid
    query = urllib.quote(urllib.unquote(query.encode('utf-8')), safe='=&?/')

    # ensure fragment is valid
    fragment = urllib.quote(urllib.unquote(fragment.encode('utf-8')))

    # piece it all back together, truncating it to a maximum of 4KB
    url = urlparse.urlunsplit((scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment))
    return url[:4096]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: Just cutting it off at 4096 characters could leave partial quoted characters. You could use the regular expression r'%.?$' to match any trailing partial escapes.

Answer (score 0):

You might use [`urlparse.urlsplit`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit) instead, but otherwise you seem to have a very straightforward solution, there.

```
protocol, domain, path, query, fragment = urlparse.urlsplit(url)
```

(You can access the domain and port separately by accessing the returned value's named properties, but as port syntax is always in ASCII it is unaffected by the IDNA encoding process.)