# how to url-safe encode a string with python? and urllib.quote is wrong

Tags: python, encoding, url-rewriting

Hello i was wondering if you know any other way to encode a string to a url-safe, because urllib.quote is doing it wrong, the output is different than expected:

If i try

> > > urllib.quote('á')

i get

'%C3%A1'

But thats not the correct output, it should be
%E1

As demostrated by the tool provided here [this site](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm)

And this is not me being difficult, the incorrect output of quote is preventing the browser to found resources, if i try

> > > urllib.quote('\images\á\some file.jpg')

And then i try with the javascript tool i mentioned i get this strings respectively

%5Cimages%5C%C3%A1%5Csome%20file.jpg

%5Cimages%5C%E1%5Csome%20file.jpg

Note how is almost the same but the url provided by quote doesn't work and the other one it does.
I tried messing with encode('utf-8) on the string provided to quote but it does not make a difference.
I tried with other spanish words with accents and the ñ they all are differently represented.

Is this a python bug?
Do you know some module that get this right?

Comment: both javascript and python are using the same encoding? Have you tried unicode? `repr('á') == "'\\xc3\\xa1'"` and `repr(u'á') == "u'\\xe1'"`

Comment: @Rob: I'm pretty sure UTF-8 is supposed to be in URLs.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912811/what-is-the-proper-way-to-url-encode-unicode-characters

Comment: `0xc3a1` is a [UTF-8 representation of _LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE_](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl).

Comment: @sarnold oh that helps, now i know i want my urls in unicode not in utf-8, but doing unicode(urllib.quote(string)) is not working.

Answer (score 7):

According to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), `%C3%A1` is correct. Characters are supposed to be converted to an octet stream using UTF-8 before the octet stream is percent-encoded. The site you link is out of date.

See [Why does the encoding's of a URL and the query string part differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366007/why-does-the-encodings-of-a-url-and-the-query-string-part-differ/5433216#5433216) for more detail on the history of handling non-ASCII characters in URLs.

Comment: could be, but none of my browsers find the resourse with the "updated" encoding.

Comment: So, any module that uses the outdated but actually working encoding?

Comment: @Guillermo, can you update your _server_ to allow newer HTTP clients to request resources as specified in the newer RFC?

Comment: I'm using web.py's internal server can't do anything about that for the time being.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, got it, i have to encode to iso-8859-1 like this

```
word = u'á'
word = word.encode('iso-8859-1')
print word
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is interpreted in ASCII by default, so even though your file may be encoded differently, your UTF-8 char is interpereted as two ASCII chars.

Try putting a comment as the first of second line of your code like this to match the file encoding, and you might need to use `u'á'` also.

```
# coding: utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using unicode strings and the numeric representation (ord) of the char?

```
>>> print '%{0:X}'.format(ord(u'á'))
%E1
```

Comment: It's a hack, but a hack may be required for a website that still requires ISO-8859-1.  Most webservers are now compliant with UTF-8, as assumed by urllib.

Comment: Works but looks like black magic, and it doesnt work with more than 1 character, and looping over all my content just doesnt seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804336/best-way-to-convert-a-unicode-url-to-ascii-utf-8-percent-escaped-in-python) it seems some guy wrote a pretty large function to convert to ascii urls, thats what i need. But i was hoping there was some encoding tool in the std lib for the job.

Comment: I spoke too soon, those functions do not output the Unicode code point that is needed.