# Python encoding characters with urllib.quote

Tags: python, encoding, urllib

I'm trying to encode non-ASCII characters so I can put them inside an url and use them in `urlopen`. The problem is that I want an encoding like JavaScript (that for example encodes `ó` as `%C3%B3`):

```
encodeURIComponent(ó)
'%C3%B3'
```

But `urllib.quote` in python returns `ó` as `%F3`:

```
urllib.quote(ó)
'%F3'
```

I want to know how to achieve an encoding like javascript's `encodeURIComponent` in Python, and also if I can encode non `ISO 8859-1` characters like Chinese. Thanks!

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338469/how-to-url-safe-encode-a-string-with-python-and-urllib-quote-is-wrong

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You want to make sure you're using unicode.

Example:

```
import urllib

s = u"ó"
print urllib.quote(s.encode("utf-8"))
```

Outputs:

`%C3%B3`

Answer (score 46):

in **Python 3** the `urllib.quote` has been renamed to [`urllib.parse.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote).

Also in Python 3 all strings are unicode strings (the byte strings are called [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes)).

Example:

```
from urllib.parse import quote

print(quote('ó'))
# output: %C3%B3
```

Comment: Upvoted, I think the Python 3 version of the answer is more relevant these days.

Comment: Note that `encodeURIComponent("!") != quote("!")`, so it's not like JS version as the OP asked.

Answer (score 3):

Note that [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent#description) does not encode the chars `A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )`. By default `urllib.parse.quote()` does encode some of these chars, you need to pass the `safe` chars list to get an equivalent encoder for Python.

In Python 3 the correct solution is

```py
from urllib.parse import quote

quote("ó", safe="!~*'()")
```