# How to decode ascii in python

Tags: python, django, encoding, ascii

I send cyrillic letters from postman to django as a parameter in url and got something like `%D0%B7%D0%B2` in variable `search_text`

actually if to print `search_text` I got something like `текст` printed

I've tried in console to make the following and didn't get an error

```
>>> a = "текст"
>>> a
'\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x81\xd1\x82'
>>> print a
текст
>>> b = a.decode("utf-8")
>>> b
u'\u0442\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0442'
>>> print b
текст
>>>
```

by without console I do have an error:

```
"""WHERE title LIKE '%%{}%%' limit '{}';""".format(search_text, limit))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How to prevent it?

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To decode urlencoded string (with '%' signs) use the [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html?#urllib.unquote):

```
import urllib
byte_string=urllib.unquote('%D0%B7%D0%B2')
```

and then you'll need to `decode` the `byte_string` from it's original encoding, i.e.:

```
import urllib
import codecs
byte_string=urllib.unquote('%D0%B7%D0%B2')
unicode_string=codecs.decode(byte_string, 'utf-8')
```

and `print(unicode_string)` will print `зв`.

The problem is with the unknown encoding. You have to know what encoding is used for the data you get. To specify the default encoding used in your script .py file, place the following line at the top:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Cyrillic might be 'cp866', 'cp1251', 'koi8_r' and 'utf-8', this are the most common. So when using `decode` try those.

Python 2 doesn't use unicode by default, so it's best to enable it or swich to Python 3. To enable unicode in .py file put the following line on top of all imports:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

So i.e. in Python 2.7.9, the following works fine:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

a="текст"
c="""WHERE title LIKE '%%{}%%' limit '{}';""".format(a, '10')
print(c)
```

Also see:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html.

Comment: This helped thanks, but I still have one problem, when I use `unicode_literals` and trying to make query with `like %search_text%`. This query somehow is case sensitive and there is difference between `Зв` and `зв`. I've tried sql `LOWER(title)` or `UPPER(title)` with `LOWER(search_text)` but it didn't helped. May be you have any ideas on this point? How to make cyrillic case insensitive select.

Comment: @Roberto: that depends on the database. Probably better in a separate question (that may already exist)

Comment: @Roberto, that has nothing to do with `unicode_literals`. `unicode_literals` just make strings in Python 2 behave like they are Python 3, precisely making all strings unicode by default. Case sensitivity is DB specific and you just might want to use `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE`, which is case insesitive.

Answer (score 2):

it depends on what encoding the django program is expecting and the strings `search_text, limit` are. usually its sufficient to do this:

```
"""WHERE title LIKE '%%{}%%' limit '{}';""".decode("utf-8").format(search_text.decode("utf-8"), limit)
```

EDIT** after reading your edits, it seems you are having problems changing back your urlparsed texts into strings. heres an example of how to do this:

```
import urlparse
print urlparse.urlunparse(urlparse.urlparse("ресторан"))
```

Comment: This also returns an error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: you really need to be more clear on the encoding used for search_text, limit and the one required by django. try this again, i have edited the code

Comment: same error: `return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: well thats because you have to also decode the string that you are formattin. i am changing the code again, make sure "limit" doesnt have any non ascii chars in it

Comment: still same error, I also tried the same in console and didn't got error. I also updated description.

Comment: to convert unicode into correct urls, you can try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804336/best-way-to-convert-a-unicode-url-to-ascii-utf-8-percent-escaped-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You can use `'{}'.format(search_text.encode('utf-8')))` to interpret the string as `utf-8`, but it probably will show your cyrillic letters as `\xd0`.

And read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work for me and returns the following error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)